# Raspbianをコマンドでサスペンドする方法

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

Raspberry Pi 3上で動作しているRaspbianで、シェルからOSのサスペンドやスリープをすることは可能でしょうか。

実現したいことは、電子ペーパー(pimoroni Inky pHAT)でピンヘッダーを全て使用したRspberry Piの省電力化です。
通電を切っても表示が消えない電子ペーパーの特徴を利用して、`サスペンド→復帰→描画→サスペンド`を数時間ごとに繰り返すことで大幅な省電力化したいのですが、方法が分かりません。

まずpm-suspendを試しました。

```
$ sudo pm-suspend
sudo: pm-suspend: コマンドが見つかりません
```

次にハイバネーションをapt-getできないか試しました。

```
$ sudo apt-get install hibernate
パッケージリストを読み込んでいます... 完了
依存関係ツリーを作成しています
状態情報を読み取っています... 完了
E: パッケージ hibernate が見つかりません
```

次に[systemctl](https://wiki.archlinux.jp/index.php/%E3%82%B5%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9A%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%81%A8%E3%83%8F%E3%82%A4%E3%83%90%E3%83%8D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88#systemd)を試しました。

```
$ sudo systemctl suspend
Failed to suspend system via logind: Sleep verb not supported
```

最後に[rtcwake](http://linux.ikoinoba.net/index.php?UID=1347981483)を試しました。

```
$ sudo rtcwake -s 60
rtcwake: assuming RTC uses UTC ...
rtcwake: /dev/rtco: unable to find device: そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません
```

[OnOff Shim](http://scruss.com/blog/2017/10/01/installing-the-pimoroni-onoff-shim-the-hard-way/) で物理的に電源を制御する方法もあるようですが、ソフトウェアで定期的に動作させる方が目的に合致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSEの [関連サイト](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/108123) では *"RasPi はハードウェア的に対応していないので難しいだろう"* という話がありました。

[代替案として以下の様な回答](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/108134) が付いていました:

> - 動かしっぱなしでも消費電力は微々たるものなので気にしない。
> - WittyPi2 等の外部ハードウェアから制御する。

参考:
[How to hibernate raspberry pi4? suspend-to-disk, aka power off state - Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/108123)

Comment: [タイマー付きコンセント](http://www.revex.jp/catalogues/view/9)で解決しました。